# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I have to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6)$.

$\alpha^{2} = 2 + 2\sqrt6 + 3$ so $f(X) = X^{2} - 5 - 2\sqrt6$ is a polynomial where $f(X) \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6)[X]$ and $f(\alpha) = 0$

I think this is the minimal polynomial we are looking for, but how do I prove this? How can I prove that this polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: You have already proved that a degree two polynomial can cancel $\alpha$. So, either it is the minimal polynomial, or you can find a **degree 1** polynomial which cancels $\alpha$. What would that imply on $\alpha$ ? Can you prove or disprove that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

$$\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)=\text{Span}_{\Bbb Q}\,\{1,\sqrt6\}$$

so

$$\sqrt2+\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)\implies \;\exists\,a,b\in\Bbb Q\;\;s.t.\;\;\sqrt2+\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt6\implies$$

$$5+2\sqrt6=a^2+6b^2+2ab\sqrt6$$

and we get a straightforward contradiction to $\;\sqrt6\notin\Bbb Q\;$ unless $\;ab-1=0\iff ab=1\;$ , but in this case we'd get

$$\;5=a^2+6b^2=a^2+\frac6{a^2}\implies 0=a^4-5a^2+6=(a^2-2)(a^2-3)\;$$

which cannot be solved over the rationals.

Thus, your element $\;\sqrt2+\sqrt3\;$ has *at least* order two over $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)\;$ , and you already found a quadratic over this field which vanishes on that element...

Comment: I literally stucked at the same task and wondered how to prove the $ab=1$ case. Now it seems so clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Simply proof, that $(a+b\sqrt{6})^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$ has no solution
       with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

Assume it is reducible, then you can write it as: $f(X) = (X-a-b\sqrt{6})(X-c-d\sqrt{6})$. Can you prove that this is not possible? for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$