# A question Monic Irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt{6}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

Given $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$.
I encounter some confusion on the monic irreducible polynomial for $\sqrt{6}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Im thinking the minimal monic irreducible polynomial of
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$. And for
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(x^2-6)$.

I cant seems to figure out the minimal  monic irreducible polynomial of
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$.

any insight is highly appreciated

Comment: Your first polynomial is not irreducible.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287579/minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt3-over-bbbq-sqrt6) solves it for the interchanged values :)

Comment: The monic irreducible polinomial of $\sqrt{6}$  you are looking for is $x-\sqrt{6}$.